# Why isn't Slade ever referred to as "Deathstroke the Terminator"?

Tags: character, teen-titans, teen-titans-go, teen-titans-go-to-the-movies

In *Teen Titans*, *Teen Titans Go*, and *Teen Titans Go to the Movies*, the villain known as Slade Wilson is simply called **Slade** (*Slaaaaaaaade*) and is never referred to by his comic book alias, **Deathstroke the Terminator**, or even simply **Deathstroke**.

Why is this? Why can't he be called **Deathstroke**?

Comment: Because those are kids' shows and someone thought "Deathstroke" would not be an appropriate name.

Comment: They jokingly called him "Deadpool" in the movie.

Comment: @PatrickWynne I think you should put your findings as an answer (with official source or something'd be better)..

Comment: Possible rights/permissions issue?

Comment: @Vishwa Yeah, unfortunately I haven't been able to find any official word on that, which is why I hesitated to make it an answer. That's just what has been reported as the reason since the animated series debuted 15 years ago. Everyone simply repeats the same claim without sourcing it. I will keep looking and post an answer if I find official word, but until then I'll leave it be in case someone else can find something I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

No official word I can find but it's widely speculated that it was done to keep the tone of the show kid-friendly. Even [wikia](http://teentitans.wikia.com/wiki/Slade) said the same:

> Slade's original comic name "Deathstroke" did not make it through the censors due to hesitance to use the word "death" in a children's animated series; thus, the character is referred to by his first name. However, his original name is mentioned in the tie-in comic Teen Titans Go! and in some foreign language versions of the show. He is also changed from an assassin and mercenary-for-hire to an enigmatic criminal mastermind.

But it's not sourced.